# Can I omit this phrase if it’s understandable?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a pen and a pencil, and I will give A a pen and B a pencil, and who will get a pen and who will get a pencil are already understandable to listeners.

In this case, can I just say “I will give a pen and a pencil respectively,” omitting “to A and B”?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of the adverb "respectively" requires two parallel lists of corresponding items. Therefore, you need to say:

> *“I will give a pen and a pencil **to A and B** respectively,”*